# Cancel input when escape is pressed

Tags: python, input

I would like to have a function that works like `input()`, but that returns `None` (for example) when <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is pressed.

I tried doing the following:

```
def input(t):
    print(t)
    text = ""
    while True:
        char = msvcrt.getche();

        if char == chr(27).encode():
            return None

        if char == b'\r':
            return text

        try:
            text += char.decode()
        except:
            pass
```

This works for the most part, but the problem is that backspace won't work, and that I get strange characters when pressing non-character keys like the arrow keys, or the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. So getche might not be the answer to my problem.

I was under the impression that this would be a common problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: You should always specify an exception to catch in the `except` line otherwise unintended exceptions will be suppressed which is never what you want

Comment: The problem is that some keys (like the arrow keys) are represented as a sequence of characters, starting with the escape key.

Answer (score 1):

I made a code using module `keyboard`. You an install it using `pip install keyboard`. It reads left,right,end,home,enter,escape,backspace and many other keys.
You can use function `read_input`. It has two options `text` and `cancel`. `text` is the text to print and `cancel` is the key which will cancel the input. If you press `escape` then it returns `None`, if `enter` then typed text.
Here is the code:

```
def read_input(text="",cancel="esc"):
    import keyboard,string as t
    print(text,end="")
    output = []
    output2 = []
    allowed = t.ascii_letters+"1234567890!@#$%^&*()-=_+{}[]|\:;',<>./?`~"+'"'
    while True:
        key = keyboard.read_event()
        k = key.name
        if key.event_type == "up":continue
        if k == cancel:print("");return None
        elif k == "enter":break
        elif k == "end":output = output+output2;output2 = []
        elif k == "home":output2 = output+output2;output = []
        elif k == "left":
            try:output2.insert(0,output.pop())
            except:pass
        elif k == "right":
            try:output.append(output2.pop(0))
            except:pass
        elif k == "space":k = " ";output.append(k)
        elif k == "backspace":output = output[:-1]
        elif k in allowed:output.append(k)
    foutput2 = ""
    for put in output:
        foutput2 += str(put)
    for put in output2:
        foutput2 += str(put)
    for i in range(0,len(foutput2)+2):keyboard.press_and_release("backspace")
    print(foutput2)
    return foutput2
```

You can use it like normal input:

```
print(read_input("Enter your name: "))
```

It has some issues on the other side.
It read keys from the whole windows, not only python.
The keys typed in first second(when executed) may be ignored.

Here is an animation:
[image: GIPHY]

Answer (score 1):

> I was under the impression that this would be a common problem

No it is not. There are two common idioms when it comes to io. First is called line oriented. It can be used in *batch mode* programs where the standard input can be redirected to a file or a pipe. In this mode, the program itself should not even try to know whether it reads from a real keyboard or from a file (well more or less, password input being the exception). The low level driver, or the input library can add some goodies like in line edition (backspace processing), but this is not directly accessible to the programmer, and in any case is not intended to be portable.

Second mode is for GUI. Here, most of the things are under programmer control: the position of input fields on the screen, their size, and optionally the processing of special characters. More exactly, it is generally processed through a graphic library like tkinter (tk), pyqt or pyside (Qt), or ...

What you ask for is a medium way. It is common for beginners to try to explore it, but after some time, we all realize that for real world programs the two common idioms are enough.

You may find this answer more philosophical that technical, and in theory there would be nothing bad in improving line edition, but in real programs, I have never found any true reason to go beyond what is currently available.